# print div just after fetching completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

**Problem:** All i have to do is Fetch the information of a user from database using his id, and then print those incoming information on pdf file or hard copy.

**Tried Solution:** i have created a method `PrintData(id)` as shown below in code, it accepts the user id as an argument then fetch all information related to it from database using ajax. and then put all information into a div. the i uses a print method to print that div. Unfortunately the `PrintElem()` method print the previous content of the div ( not the current content which we fetch from server related to that id). i am able to do it by adding another print button with the div, but i want to print those information as soon as `PrintData()` method set those information into that div. Here is the sample code i tried to achieve it. Feel free to ask me if you any more information.

```
function PrintData(id){
    var Data= "task=showuserdetail&id="+id;
    $.ajax({
        url:"taskprocess.php" ,
        data:Data,
        cache:false,
        dataType:'json',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(output){
            if(output[0] !=0){
                $('#viewDetail').show();     //main Div name
                $('#userID_Retrieve').html(id);
                $('#name').html(output[0]);
                $('#userName').html(output[1])
                $('#accountType').html(output[2]);
                $('#accountGroup').html(output[4]);
                $('#creationDate').html(output[6]);
                $('#streetAddress').html(output[7]);
                $('#state').html(output[8]);
                $('#city').html(output[9]);
                $('#birthDate').html(output[10]);
                $('#phoneNumber').html(output[11]);
            }
        },
        error:function (a, b , c){
            alert(a+" "+" "+c);
        }
    });
    PrintElem('#userDetail');
    return false;
}
```

Other MEthods

```
function PrintElem(elem)
{
    Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) 
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Your details</title>');        
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write(data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong about what your asking as your question isn't 100% clear....But, I believe the problem lies in your misunderstanding of an $.ajax asynchronous call.

I believe you are looking for the following to happen

1. Make web request
2. When response is received update the div
3. Call PrintElem with the new div contents

In your current code however you do step number 3 when there is no guarantee that step 2 has ever been completed. This means you are actually calling PrintElem before its been updated.

Long story short - make sure your call to PrintElem is in your $.ajax success so that it only calls PrintElem after updating the div

```
$.ajax({
    url:"taskprocess.php" ,
    data:Data,
    cache:false,
    dataType:'json',
    type:'POST',
    success: function(output){
        if(output[0] !=0){
            $('#viewDetail').show();     //main Div name
            $('#userID_Retrieve').html(id);
            $('#name').html(output[0]);
            $('#userName').html(output[1])
            $('#accountType').html(output[2]);
            $('#accountGroup').html(output[4]);
            $('#creationDate').html(output[6]);
            $('#streetAddress').html(output[7]);
            $('#state').html(output[8]);
            $('#city').html(output[9]);
            $('#birthDate').html(output[10]);
            $('#phoneNumber').html(output[11]);

            // now we can call this
            PrintElem('#userDetail');

        }
    },
    error:function (a, b , c){
        alert(a+" "+" "+c);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that too but unfortunately it leads to crash my browser :(

Comment: Are you able to provide details of this crash?

Comment: actually the print function prints the previous data of div rather than newly updated data. and when i again try to fetch new user's data it prints the current data.

Comment: crash message is like this 

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_lCUj1FXbx48/SL-W5bBvPjI/AAAAAAAABrg/LisYPdXsbxs/s400/chrome-chrash.jpg